# Neo4J repository not wired everywhere

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I've defined a Neo4j repository as follow (code is in Kotlin but it's very close to Java) :

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository : GraphRepository<User> {

    fun findByEmail(email: String): User?

    @Query("match (n:User)-[:IS_AUTH]->(:Permission {name: {0}}) where id(n) = {1} return n")
    fun authorizedUser(permission: String, userId: Long): User?

}
```

In a controller, I've written:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/company")
open class CreateCompanyController {

    @Autowired private lateinit var userRepo: UserRepository

    @RequestMapping(method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.POST))
    @ResponseBody
    fun createCompany(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) name: String,
                      @RequestParam(value = "siret", required = true) siret: Long) : ResponseEntity<String> {

        val connectedUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication.principal as User

        val testUser = userRepo.findByEmail("test@company.com")

        if (!PermissionManager().hasAuthorizationFor(PermissionManager.ADMIN_ALL, connectedUser))
            return ResponseEntity("You're not authorized to create a company", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)


        return ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK)

    }

}
```

In the code above, the `userRepo` property is set well (aka. its value is not null).

I want to have this UserRepository in a custom service. So, I've coded:

```
@Service
open class PermissionManager {

    companion object {
        val ADMIN_ALL = "ADMIN_ALL"
    }

    @Autowired private lateinit var userRepo: UserRepository

    fun hasAuthorizationFor(permissionName: String, user: User): Boolean {
        return userRepo.authorizedUser(permissionName, user.id!!) != null
    }

}
```

But in this case, the `userRepo` property is not initialized.

I've written the PersistenceContext class as:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("persistence")
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("persistence.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
open class PersistenceContext : Neo4jConfiguration() {
    @Bean override  fun getSessionFactory(): SessionFactory {
        return SessionFactory("persistence.domain")
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    open override fun getSession(): Session {
        return super.getSession()
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is why is the userRepo set in my controller but not in my service ?

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `PermissionManager` You should also inject the spring managed `PermissionManager` instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Exact :( I've forgotten I've created a new instance of PermissionManager if my test. Thanks.